# Identify Start and End Dates from Consecutive Dates

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create an output where >=200 units have been sold for consecutive dates. I used lead function to get the next start date but unable to get 05/06 end date for 05/04 start date. Do we need some sort of loop?

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_sls
(date1 date, Sales int);

INSERT INTO sales
(date1, Sales)
VALUES
('2019-05-01', 200),
('2019-05-02', 200),
('2019-05-03', 100),
('2019-05-04', 200),
('2019-05-05', 200),
('2019-05-06', 200),
('2019-05-10', 200),
('2019-05-11', 200),
('2019-05-12', 100);
```

I've written the below code but cannot get any far.

```
select date1, sales, rank() over(partition by sales order by date1)
from (
  select a.date1, b.sales from
  (select date1 from sales
  where date1<'2019-05-07') a
  left join
  (select date1, sales from sales
   where sales>=200) b
   on a.date1=b.date1
  ) x
```

Expected Output:

```
date_start|date_end
'2019-05-01'|'2019-05-02'
'2019-05-04'|'2019-05-06'
'2019-05-10'|'2019-05-11'
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-isands problem.  Here is a solution that uses SQL Server syntax:

```
select min(date1), max(date1), sales
from (select s.*, row_number() over (partition by sales order by date1) as seqnum
      from sales s
     ) s
group by dateadd(day, - seqnum, date1), sales;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7d52b917d6ec6cfd193ca489dcfba342) is a db<>fiddle.  This gives the adjacent values for the same sales number.

This is a better answer to your specific question:

```
select min(date1), max(date1)
from (select s.*, row_number() over (order by date1) as seqnum
      from sales s
      where sales >= 200
     ) s
group by dateadd(day, - seqnum, date1)
order by 1
```

[And the db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=221b085c644e17943b3cb536863e0f30).